# Loop through mysql table row and check if any column matches a set number in php

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to loop through a mysql table and check if a row contains the number I specify:

Here is what I have:

mysql table with numbers:

mysql table:

```
no1|no2|no3|no4|no5
 1   3   5   2   6
 4   7   8   9   8
 2   6   9   1   0
 ...
```

For Example: I have number 
4 5 3 7

So in the first row i should get a total of 2 as there are numbers 3 and 5 first row and this numbers are in the number I have specified.

In the second row I should get a total of 1 as only a 4 is in the row and the number i have specified.

And in the last row total should be 0 as there are no matches.

I hope its clear.

I have tried the following but it dont work I hope someone can help me work it out thanks in advance.

```
$lottono1=4;
$lottono2=5;
$lottono3=3;
$lottono4=7;

$no1 = 0;
$no2 = 0;
$no3 = 0;
$no4 = 0;

do { ?>
// i done the following if code for each numbers but
//putting this only to take less space

if (($row_Recordset1['no1']=$lottono1) || ($row_Recordset1['no1']=$lottono2) || ($row_Recordset1['no1']=$lottono3) || ($row_Recordset1['no1']=$lottono4)) {
      $no1=1;

  } 

while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1));
```

Comment: Have you tried to take the do... while to a "while", because for the First loop trough the arrays are uninitialized!

Answer (score 3):

```
select *,
if(no1 in (4,5,3,7),1,0)+
if(no2 in (4,5,3,7),1,0)+
if(no3 in (4,5,3,7),1,0)+
if(no4 in (4,5,3,7),1,0)+
if(no5 in (4,5,3,7),1,0) as found
from table
```

Comment: Nick is it possible to get sums of each number for example:
SELECT * , if( no1
IN ( 4, 5, 3, 2 ) , 1, 0 ) AS number1

Comment: Sorry, I haven't understood exactly what you're looking for. Please update your question with an example. :) Maybe sum(if(no1 in (4,5,3,7),1,0)) as number1, but I'm not sure that you need this.

Comment: I think this should do the trick:
select *,
SUM(if(no1 in (4,5,3,7),1,0))AS numberone
exactly my thoughts will it give me sum for each number in each row? if there are two same numbers in one row in the table i would like to count it as 1.

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish with PHP/MySQL you can do the following:

```
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM table';

 $result = mysql_query($query) or die();
 $matchValues = array(4,5,3,7);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     $counter = 0;
     foreach($matchValues as $value)
     {
         if(in_array($value, $row))
         {
             $counter++;
         }
     }
     print "Searched row and found $counter matches<br/>";
 }
```

Comment: thank you but i dont seem to get the correct answer and the reason i want to sum for each number is if there is a same number more than one in a row i would like it to be counted as 1.

Comment: I changed the order to get what I believe you're looking for.  It will only increment the counter once for each matched instance inside of the row.  Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Well for one, your operators are wrong in your "if" conditions (you're setting rather than comparing).

Regardless i'd do something more like:

```
$numbers_to_match = array(4,5,3,7) ;  
$query = mysql_query("select * from `table` where ____",connection_here);
$matches[] = array();
$i=0;
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $matches[$i]=0;
    foreach($r as $val){
        if (in_array($val,$numbers_to_match)){
            $matches[$i]++;
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
print_r($matches);
```

Untested, but this should give you an array that lists the number of matches for each row

Comment: i havent got an correct answer I would like to get sum for each number but it doesnt work probably. I hope someone out there can help me sort it out. thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "I would like to get sum for each number"? This script will give you the number of matches in each row as per your original question. If you're trying to get a sum of all matches, then you can make $matches an integer rather than an array and just add to it each time any row matches. What are you trying to do here?